# How to get last inserted id using AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I know how to get last inserted id with PHP in WordPress by using this:

```
$wpdb->insert_id;
```

But is there a way of getting this id on AJAX success and update a hidden field value with it?

Comment: You can echo it in the PHP file itself... and then you access it in `success` callback

Comment: Yes, there is. Please show your js, and the php code it calls

Comment: can you give your json array that returns from php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server Side

```
    function yourFn(){

        //Your code
        echo $wpdb->insert_id;

    }
```

Client Side

```
    $.ajax({url: server_side_url, success: function(result){
            $(Inputfield).val(result);
    }});
```